# FastAPI: How to format a field using a function every time that field is accessed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model that has two fields: phone and pan_image.

- Phone is the primary key.
- The pan_image is an image link.

I need to send the image data in base64 rather than the image itself. For this purpose I've created and tested the getData function(imported below). I'm unable to figure out how to pass the store_photo through my getData function everytime it's accessed. Any suggestions would be very helpful

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, String
from app.models.custom_field import getData

Base = declarative_base()

class BusinessStorePhotoInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "business_store_photo_info"

    phone = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    store_photo = Column(String)
```

I've tried hybrid_property, hybrid_method and trying to modify it in the root_validator or in the schema so far. The following is some of the commented code of what I tried. It didn't work

```
    # @hybrid_property
    # def length(self):
    #     return getData(self.store_photo)

    # @hybrid_method
    # def contains(self):
    #     return getData(self.store_photo)

    # @hybrid_method
    # def intersects(self):
    #     return getData(self.store_photo)
```

Comment: @python_user I'm not using it here but it's one of the dependencies in my whole project and chatGPT told me to use it, although it's code was buggy and unsalvagable

Comment: Please provide a complete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question is very vague, inconsistent and incomplete.